# Fragment can not be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I am getting this error while implementing Fragment tabhost.

I am basically trying to call an activity in tab view which extends Fragment.

I also tried with extending FragmentActivity, but it gives an error on "onCreateView" method.
Upon removing @override annotation from "onCreateView" method, and running the app lead to following error.

```
    11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.variouscal.calculators.FragmentTab1 cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
    11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
    11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:339)
    11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:307)
    11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.widget.TabHost.invokeOnTabChangeListener(TabHost.java:391)
    11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime

(4255):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:376)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
11-27 20:54:06.937: E/AndroidRuntime(4255):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the code for the line your error is on and the class FragmentTab1

Comment: Have you tried checking your imports to make sure you are referring to  `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.fragment`?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that there are two versions of `Fragment`:

- `android.app.Fragment`
- `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Be sure to import the correct one and be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Without code this is more of a guess but it sounds like your are trying to use `android.app.Fragment` with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` which you cannot do